# find last record of one to many relation on mysql with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have four table in my database

> Inspector: id,name,type,status,email
>
> State: id,name,parent
>
> Patient: id,name,age,national_code
>
> Patient_Log: id,patient_id,inspector_id,state_id,breathing,body_movement,face_movement,gag,cough,cornea,pupil,doll_eye,sedation,status,update

i use this query now:

```
 SELECT patient.id, patient.name, patient.age, patient.national_code,
 pLog.id AS pLog_id, pLog.inspector_id, pLog.state_id, pLog.breathing, pLog.sedation,
 inspecor.name AS ins_name, inspecor.type AS ins_type, inspecor.status AS ins_status
 state.name AS state_name
 FROM patient
 JOIN patient_log AS pLog ON pLog.patient_id = patient.id AND pLog.id = 
 (SELECT MAX(patient_log.id) FROM patient_log WHERE patient_log.patient_id = patient.id)
 JOIN inspector ON inspector.id = pLog.inspector_id
 JOIN state ON state.id = pLog.state_id
 WHERE pLog.status = 1
 ORDER BY pLog.update DESC
 LIMIT 30
```

this Query it's work! and my result is true!
but now my patient table have 1500 record and patient_log table have 8000 record with this Query i get the result in 16 second!!!!!!

if i remove this section from my query i get the result in 0.02 second but my result not true and return first record from patient_log:

```
 AND pLog.id = (SELECT MAX(patient_log.id) FROM patient_log WHERE 
 patient_log.patient_id = patient.id)
```

How can I optimize my query to get the correct result?

Comment: indexes are always a great area to look. Also you have a correlated subquery. `inspector_id` ... `state_id` ,,, `pLog.update`

Comment: This query doesn't work. Please don't provide incorrect information. It's a waste of time.

Comment: why doesn't work? I currently use it, but its efficiency is low. So I want to optimize it....

Comment: No you don't. You possibly use some other query, of which this is an edited extract

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a compound index on `patient_log.patient_id` and `patient_log.id`